Is it physically possible for an ordered system to endure forever?
I am seeking to understand whether my theological views align with the current understanding of the second law of thermodynamics. As a physicalist, I believe that all ontological existents consist of spatiotemporal "bodies" and their positive attributes. Consequently, I hold that nothing exists in the universe beyond matter and energy, which originate and annihilate in succession (see this entry and this video for more on my theological physicalism). My view includes the belief that the afterlife is a physical system within a finite volume where Paradise endures eternally, allowing for unending blessings to its inhabitants.
However, the second law of thermodynamics states that the entropy of an isolated system within a fixed volume increases and never decreases, leading all such systems to eventually reach heat equilibrium, thereby eliminating ordered systems. To reconcile this, one might suggest that the second law allows for a decrease in entropy but typically sees an increase.
My question is: Does the current understanding of the second law of thermodynamics categorically state that it is physically impossible for the entropy of an isolated system to decrease, similar to how the first law prohibits the creation of matter or energy from nothing? Or does it simply assert that entropy usually increases, making a decrease extremely unlikely but not physically impossible?
Also, is it technically possible for a set of simultaneous and highly coordinated quantum mechanical effects to cause the entire isolated system's entropy to decrease? If this is merely extremely improbable but not physically impossible, then the difficulty would seem to go away, since the process could technically be actualized by God given His omnipotence.
[Note: The first part of my question has been addressed here, but not the second part of my question. I am specifically interested in whether our current understanding of the laws of physics allows for a mechanism through which a physical system in the form of an ordered residence may endure forever.]

Possible duplicate

Thank you for the link. However, it does not fully answer my questions.

It is also entirely possible to set up conditions so thermodynamics runs the other way briefly https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-019-10333-7 . But this takes a big, elaborate setup to achieve for even single molecules, and exponentially more for larger systems. Sure, you could have God fixing entropy in heaven this way, but it would be essentially him puppeteering the physics of its contents. Finite heavens (or inhabitants of heavens) also have finite phase spaces, so they will eventually repeat.

Thank you for your answer. That answers my question.

You might also consider that theological views generally include ideas about minds and God. We have no physics theory of either. All we can say is that the mind arises from the brain, and physics can describe the brain's behavior. But that doesn't say what the mind itself is. And we can't even observe God, so we have no way to even start.

You might find this post of interest - Does physics explain why the laws and behaviors observed in biology are as they are?

Thank you for the link. I generally try to maintain my belief in the intuitive axioms and metaphysical principles (such as causality and physicalism) for the purpose of avoiding unhealthy scepticism, although I do recognise the role of science in refining our understanding of these metaphysical principles without completely overturning them. Due to this commitment to physicalism, I hold that it is far more reasonable for theists to believe that God is spatiotemporal than not.

I obviously agree that we do not have the means to study the "physics" of God in the sense of making observations and formulating precise laws that describe the succession of divine states within God. However, I also think it is possible to know many things about God in a general way outside of scriptural information, particularly through employing various metaphysical principles in sound a fortiori arguments. I have provided two links for my theological views in the first paragraph of the question.
